# OKTA SSO Authentication - Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, okta, spring-cloud-gateway

We are developing an angular app​lication​ and ​microservices using spring boot which will act as a backend​.  ​There are around 4 microservices and using ​​Spring cloud api gateway​ between angular app and microservices

We want to implement SSO with OKTA. And we are planning to implement all authentication logic in the api gateway.

As per my understanding -

From ANGULAR, requests will go to Spring Cloud Gateway which will redirect to OKTA and a custom login page will be prompted. User will enter the details and then access token will be received at UI from OKTA via API gateway.

If user tried to access microservices api, GW can check for access token and if valid token then allow or it will redirect to OKTA.

Is this approach correct or should we implement OKTA directly at ANGULAR app

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One dodgy thing which I can see - usually all calls to µSvc are done as XHR ones. If you try to call from your SPA w/o having an access token, then your gateway won't be able to redirect your user's browser to a login page.

If I were you, I'd probably go with having SPA working with Okta directly on obtaining an access token and GW only do validation.

Sorry hard to say something definite not knowing more.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe your approach is a good one. I believe it's best to implement the authentication server-side with Spring Security. Then use good ol' session cookies to secure communication between your Angular app and your gateway. That's how we do it in JHipster. You can see read my [Micro Frontends for Java Microservices](https://auth0.com/blog/micro-frontends-for-java-microservices/) blog post for more information.

Comment: thanks for quick response. In jhipster's case, angular and spring boot app runs on same server. In my case, angular and microservices deployed separately. How api gateway will share cookies. Can you guide me to any sample example ? Thanks again

Comment: If you're deploying the SPA and gateway to separate servers, you cannot use this pattern. You have to do the authentication in the SPA when the backend is on a different domain.